# React - component is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

After receiving data from the DB server, you try to render it, but the console log shows the data, but the component is not rendered. What's the reason?

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    readRequest().then(setTodos);
    console.log()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos.map((todo) => {
        console.log(todo);
        console.log(todo.text);
        <div key={todo._id}>
          {todo.text}
          {`${todo.completed}`}
        </div>
      })}
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
  );
```

[image]

The picture is a screen capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.map` callback does not return anything.

Change the `{` to `(`:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos.map((todo) => ( // <-- here
        <div key={todo._id}>
          {todo.text}
          {`${todo.completed}`}
        </div>
      ))}
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
  );
```

Or use the `return` keyword.

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos.map((todo) => {
        return (<div key={todo._id}>
          {todo.text}
          {`${todo.completed}`}
        </div>);
      })}
      <p>dfdf</p>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you. It's settled thanks to you :)
However so why does the callback function wrap it up with () instead of {}?